# Using <strong> or <span> within html select option

Tags: html, css, select

I'm trying to style the inside of a select option.  This is the code I'm using to display the various parts of results from my sql query ...

```
echo '<option value="'.$colour_id.'">'.$range_name.' - '.$colour.$plank_display.$code_display.'</option>';
```

I am trying to show $colour & $plank_display in bold/strong

I have tried ..

```
echo '<option value="'.$colour_id.'">'.$range_name.' - <span style="font-weight: bold;">'.$colour.$plank_display.'</span>'.$code_display.'</option>';
```

and ...

```
echo '<option value="'.$colour_id.'">'.$range_name.' - <strong>'.$colour.$plank_display.'</strong>'.$code_display.'</option>';
```

but neither seem to be yielding the results I am looking for.

There is no other styling applied to the form, neither is there even a stylesheet attached to the page yet.

Any ideas?  Or am I going about this in the wrong way.

I can apply styling to the option to make the whole line bold using css in a style sheet, but I just want this specific bit to stand out.

Comment: Can you give us the code generated by PHP ? Because at the first sight it seems correct.

Comment: <option value="348">Spacia - <span style="font-weight: bold;">Sift Stone Graphite - (305 x 457)</span> - (SS5S6113)</option>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styling select dropdown and options are always difficult as they vary from browser to browser.
I've used [Dropkick](http://dropkickjs.com/) plugin for custom dropdown on my webpage and its really great as its very easy to customize as per your requirement.

Comment: Although this doesn't do as the original question asked, it has solved a different problem I was looking at, ty :)

Answer (score -1):

Despite of adding a tag, better if you style the Options using CSS's  nth-child property.

1. Andorra
2. Grandvalira
3. Vallnord

e.g. If you want to appear 2nd option bold from the list, then you can use following code:

```
option:nth-child(2) {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Here is Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sotiris/sqshN/